# Rails 5 - Retrieving MiniMagick-ed version of image (CarrierWave/Google Cloud Storage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave

I'm currently using Google Cloud Storage and CarrierWave to handle my file uploading.

Just to be able to explain the "problem" clearly, lets assume I have a model called `User` that has the column `avatar` which holds the image string.

After the user uploads their file, this is done:

```
version :foo1 do
  process :auto_orient
  process resize_to_fill: [150, 150]
end

version :foo2 do
  process :auto_orient
  process resize_to_fill: [250, 250]
end

version :foo3 do
  process :auto_orient
  process resize_to_fill: [350, 350]
end
```

Which successfully creates the various versions of the image in my bucket.

So the problem is upon looking at my logs, I realised that when i do

```
<%= image_tag(User.avatar.foo1.url) %>
```

The query is actually being performed for every single variation of the image, so it calls the original one, along with `foo1-3`, before rendering `foo1`.

So the question is, how do i retrieve the specific variation needed only? (I'm not sure if my uploader or carrierwave code is essential here. If it is, let me know and i will include it in)

For reference, this is what I see in my logs when I perform `User.avatar.foo1.url`, which leads me to think that I'm making an "excessive" call to Google Cloud Storage. (I replaced certain details which i thought might be sensitive with foo)

```
Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo == 200 (374 bytes) 69ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Bucket:foo
 @etag="CAI=",
 @id="foo",
 @kind="storage#bucket",
 @location="ASIA-SOUTHEAST1",
 @metageneration="2",
 @name="foo",
 @project_number="foo",
 @self_link="https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 05:50:41 +0000,
 @updated=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 07:08:46 +0000>

Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2FWeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2FWeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg == 200 (926 bytes) 62ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Object:0x007f98b3332220
 @bucket="foo",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @crc32c="5SNA/w==",
 @etag="CNrr8om4h9sCEAE=",
 @generation="1526377710663130",
 @id=
  "foo/uploads/profile/avatar/328/WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg/1526377710663130",
 @kind="storage#object",
 @md5_hash="g6cUQBBiGC31uRJUtM1dng==",
 @media_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2FWeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?generation=1526377710663130&alt=media",
 @metageneration="1",
 @name="uploads/profile/avatar/328/WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @self_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2FWeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @size="5499",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:30 +0000,
 @time_storage_class_updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:30 +0000,
 @updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:30 +0000>

Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo == 200 (374 bytes) 53ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Bucket:foo
 @etag="CAI=",
 @id="foo",
 @kind="storage#bucket",
 @location="ASIA-SOUTHEAST1",
 @metageneration="2",
 @name="foo",
 @project_number="foo",
 @self_link="https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 05:50:41 +0000,
 @updated=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 07:08:46 +0000>

Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Fthumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Fthumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg == 200 (950 bytes) 58ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Object:foo
 @bucket="foo",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @crc32c="XDUTLQ==",
 @etag="CN/7+oq4h9sCEAE=",
 @generation="1526377712893407",
 @id=
  "foo/uploads/profile/avatar/328/thumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg/1526377712893407",
 @kind="storage#object",
 @md5_hash="CRdX68ncBsEqJFY/uRg03A==",
 @media_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/deanslist-9322/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Fthumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?generation=1526377712893407&alt=media",
 @metageneration="1",
 @name="uploads/profile/avatar/328/thumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @self_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Fthumb_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @size="5923",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:32 +0000,
 @time_storage_class_updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:32 +0000,
 @updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:32 +0000>

Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo == 200 (374 bytes) 59ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Bucket:0x007f98b3252328
 @etag="CAI=",
 @id="foo",
 @kind="storage#bucket",
 @location="ASIA-SOUTHEAST1",
 @metageneration="2",
 @name="foo",
 @project_number="1028403006209",
 @self_link="https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 05:50:41 +0000,
 @updated=Wed, 20 Dec 2017 07:08:46 +0000>

Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Ftestimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?
200
#<Hurley::Response GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Ftestimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg == 200 (974 bytes) 59ms>
Success - #<Google::Apis::StorageV1::Object:0x007f98b6a82a40
 @bucket="foo",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @crc32c="VFIp7Q==",
 @etag="CJbO2Yu4h9sCEAE=",
 @generation="1526377714444054",
 @id=
  "foo/uploads/profile/avatar/328/testimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg/1526377714444054",
 @kind="storage#object",
 @md5_hash="QGE8XArsE5C9QD2A6ybpVg==",
 @media_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Ftestimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg?generation=1526377714444054&alt=media",
 @metageneration="1",
 @name=
  "uploads/profile/avatar/328/testimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @self_link=
  "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/foo/o/uploads%2Fprofile%2Favatar%2F328%2Ftestimonial_WeChat_Image_20180112102430.jpg",
 @size="2481",
 @storage_class="NEARLINE",
 @time_created=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:34 +0000,
 @time_storage_class_updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:34 +0000,
 @updated=Tue, 15 May 2018 09:48:34 +0000>
```

Comment: @have you included this `include CarrierWave::MiniMagick`?

Comment: possibly see this it can help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/rails-image-upload-using-carrierwave-and-devise--cms-25681

Comment: @Gabbar the tutorial doesn’t really help, since its not using google cloud storage... i’m not sure if the calls for the images are similar with AWS. But yes i’m using mini magick, which allows me to successfully resize and save copies of my images.